# Find the values for which the matrix A is positive definite.

Tags: linear-algebra

I would like to know how I can solve this exercise:

*Find the values of $\lambda$ so that the matrix is positive definite*

$$A=  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
        2 & \lambda & -1 \\ 
        \lambda & 2 & 0 \\ 
        -1 & 0 & 2 \\
             \end{array} } \right]$$

I expect your suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you familiar with Sylvester's criterion? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester's_criterion

Comment: A symmetric matrix is positive definite iff its eigenvalues are all positive.

Comment: Maybe the 4th characterization [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix#Characterizations)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the determinant of submatrices is positive.

$|2| > 0$

$\begin{vmatrix} 2 & \lambda \\ \lambda & 2 \end{vmatrix} > 0$

$\begin{vmatrix} 2 & \lambda & -1 \\ \lambda & 2 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 2\end{vmatrix} > 0$

then you can get the $\lambda$ value.